# Mockito-python with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, mockito

I wanted to use mockito with python version **2.6** & **2.7**.
I have downloaded the latest version of mockito package and tried to use it. But I am unable to use it. The package is imported successfully but when I am using any function it is failing.
Do you have any idea about the compatibility of mockito with python version?
I could not find any documentation around it. I mostly saw that it with python **3.0**.

Help me with your suggestions or help around this?

Comment: Did you mean mockito?  I couldn't find your spelling of mokito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://github.com/edgeware/mockito-python) shows that mockito was tested with at least the following Python versions:

- Python 2.4.6
- Python 2.5.4
- Python 2.6.1
- Python 2.7
- Python 3.1.2